# Change delimiters for navigating word-wise

Tags: linux, vim, editing

When programming/writing I heavily use *word-wise* commands, for example "move to the left/right by one word", "delete next/last word" by pressing `Ctrl` (+`left`,`backspace`...).

The problem I have is, when the text I am editing contains symbols which will not be recognized as words, therefore `ctrl + right` will jump over a sequence of symbols AND a *regular* word after that.

Ideally I want to be able to set the delimiting characters for word-wise operations to space, tab, newline and opening and closing brackets - maybe also arithmetic operators (similar to how Eclipse handles it).

I am using Linux. Do you know any way how to change my settings system-wide or alternatively for xterm and (g)vim individually to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most likely, system-wide won't work. VIM is easy, you can set the characters that define the identifier using the **iskeyword** setting. In your case, there is too much in it, and you need to remove the ones you do need, or redefine it by adding the ones you do want. eg:

```
:set isk=9,32,50-51
```

This will set keyword detection to spaces, tabs and parentheses.

However, in VIM you can jump based on word and WORDs, where the first is defined by the abovementioned **iskeyword** setting, while the latter will jump over *all* non-blank characters. Maybe, that's the motion you want. You can read more about this in the help (**:help w**).

Comment: @tchrist: even though, navigating using the arrow keys goes against the philosophy of VIM, it is a good start learning to use VIM. This [blogpost](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/07/29/everyone-who-tried-to-convince-me-to-use-vim-was-wrong/) makes an argument for keeping the learning curve low, in contrary to what most people hear. Assuming that the guy who asked the question just started to use VIM.

Answer (score 4):

Instead of holding down the control key and pressing the left/right cursor keys, why not use Vim's normal mode word motion commands?

- `w`/`W` - move to start of next word/WORD
- `e`/`E` - move to end of next word/WORD
- `b`/`B` - move to beginning of previous word/WORD
- `ge`/`gE` - move to end of previous word/WORD

You can read up on the difference between a *word* and a *WORD* by running [`:help word`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/motion.html#word).

Comment: Yeah, really. I had no idea that Control-LEFT_ARROW did anything.  It certainly seems a pain in the butt.  The whole point in vi is to let you keep your fingers on the home row even for editing, so that you can touich type quickly and without thinking. Playing Twister with the keyboard hitting weird chord combinations will break your Zen.  WEB/web movement ommands are definitely where it’s at.  I use ft/FT quite a bit, too. I’ve used vi for going on 30 years now, so it’s in muscle-memory.